# What does -> mean in WordPress?

Tags: php, plugin-development

I'm bit confused about the meaning of this line:

```
$show_title = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->get_setting( 'show_title' );
```

Is `->` available in PHP, or it used only within WordPress.

Comment: You should learn OOP programming. its a vary basic thing of OOP.

Answer (score 2):

**NO** `->` is not wordpress specific, it is object operator in php.

When you want to call a method of an instance then you call the method with `->`

```
Class SomeClass{

  function example(){
   return 'This is an example function'
  }

}
$obj = new SomeClass();
$obj->example(); // we are calling example function with -> operator
```

Additional Info: there is one more operator **::** which is used to call for static methods of a class.

Comment: Also show an example the process of accessing this $show_title = Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->get_setting( 'show_title' );

Comment: @JayaJeeth This is oops concept. Try it. for a help. let me give a little info on this you have asekd.

Comment: `Ninja_Forms()->form( $form_id )->get_setting( 'show_title' );` `Ninja_Forms()` is a function which returns an object instance. so calling an method of it is `form($form_id)` and now this too returns an object instance. finally calling the method `get_setting('show_title');`

Comment: Nice. can you write a small program using this above for better understanding.

Comment: @JayaJeeth try the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) on object orientation and this tutorial from [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bH5s3/0/1)